# Why does mysql give different result for this summations?

Tags: mysql, datatypes, sum

Can someone help understand the following behavior?

```
mysql> select (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3);
+-------------------+
| (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) |
+-------------------+
|            1.0000 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select (1/3);
+--------+
| (1/3)  |
+--------+
| 0.3333 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select(0.3333 + 0.3333 + 0.3333);
+----------------------------+
| (0.3333 + 0.3333 + 0.3333) |
+----------------------------+
|                     0.9999 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why does the first sum of the fractions is summed up to 1 while when summing the decimal equivalent we get 0.9999?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or **Why don’t my numbers add up?**](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @ypercube:But why in the last sum it is not rounded up?

Comment: Why should be rounded? `0.3+0.3+0.3` makes `0.9`. Why would `0.3333 + 0.3333 + 0.3333` make `1.0000` and not `0.9999`?

Comment: Because `(1/3) = 0.3333` according to the second select. Therefore based on this (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) is exactly the same with (0.3333 + 0.3333 + 0.3333). But it is not apparently. But why?

Comment: Well, `1/3` is not `0.3333`. That's what my naive math says. Read the link I posted above (there are also several other web sites with info about float point arithmetic.) The main issue is that all floating point numbers (1.0, 0.33333, whatever) are stored in binary arithmetic. The result you see (1.0 or 0.333 or 0.9999) is the result of converting the internal (binary) representation into decimal.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. The question is why this binary representation in the first case is displayed as 0.3333 and in the last as 1.0?Is is because the result is considered a float in the last so it shows 4 digits and is rounded up as a double in the first? Honestly I can not understand this. I am trying to understand it based on the datatype used to store vs show the value and any implied conversions that mysql may use.

Comment: 1/3 is not 0.333 but 0.33333333 at infinite.It`s just that mysql cant represent that.

Comment: Look up the floating point representations and do the arithmetic yourself. **All floating point numbers are approximate, with the exception of small integers.** You have no control over the internal rounding, only over the external rounding for display purposes.

Comment: Please don't close this. I have an answer.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens:`Look up the floating point representations and do the arithmetic yourself.` What does that mean?Write code to implement the arithmetic?Is that what is usually done?

Answer (score 1):

[Peter is correct](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/why-does-mysql-give-different-result-for-this-summations#comment137481_75940). Here is why:

Surprisingly, you can control the precision for division.

If you try setting [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) to the max value of 30, mysqld still does the rounding

Here is a demonstration from MySQL 5.5.37 on my laptop (Windows 7)

```
mysql> set global div_precision_increment = 30;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set div_precision_increment = 30;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3;
+----------------------------------+
| 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3                  |
+----------------------------------+
| 1.000000000000000000000000000000 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/3;
+----------------------------------+
| 1/3                              |
+----------------------------------+
| 0.333333333333333333333333333333 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       0.999999999999999999999999999999 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

[You mentioned in your comment something about the precision being 4 digits](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/why-does-mysql-give-different-result-for-this-summations#comment137478_75940). That's because 4 is the default value for [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment).

This is why the [**FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function was made.

Let me print the answer to that sum using `FORMAT(...,29)` and `FORMAT(...,30)`:

```
mysql> select FORMAT(0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333,29);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333,29) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.00000000000000000000000000000                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select FORMAT(0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333,30);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333333333333333333,30) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0.999999999999999999999999999999                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The internal rounding becomes your responsibility when you use [**FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format).

## Give it a Try !!!

**CAVEAT** : The [**FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function will inject commas into the whole number part if it is >= 1000. You can simply use `REPLACE(FORMAT(...,..),',','')` to strip commas and only have digits and one decimal point.

## UPDATE 2014-09-14 21:16 EDT

You just said in [your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/why-does-mysql-give-different-result-for-this-summations/76445#comment138716_76445)

> +1.Very useful answer. But my core question is why doesn't the select 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3; give 0.9999? The 1/3 is 0.3333 according to the second select

As I already explained, [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) is set to 4 and mysqld is controlling the rounding.

To see this for a fact, let's use two more math formulas

1. `select 1/7 + 2/7 + 4/7 sum1;`
2. `select 1/7 + 2/7 + 2/7 sum2;`

Let's look at the answers with the default [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) of 4:

```
mysql> show variables like 'div_precision_increment';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| div_precision_increment | 4     |
+-------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/7 + 2/7 + 4/7 sum1;
+--------+
| sum1   |
+--------+
| 1.0000 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/7 + 2/7 + 2/7 sum2;
+--------+
| sum2   |
+--------+
| 0.7143 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since `sum2` is `5/7`, the answer would be `0.714285714285714285714285714285714285714285...`

Because [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) is set to `4`, mysqld did the rounding. It effectively ran `SELECT FORMAT(5/7,4);` thus, rounding `0.714285714285714285714285714285714285714285...` to 4 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Let change the [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) to 10 and run `sum2` again

```
mysql> set div_precision_increment = 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'div_precision_increment';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| div_precision_increment | 10    |
+-------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/7 + 2/7 + 2/7 sum2;
+--------------+
| sum2         |
+--------------+
| 0.7142857143 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) is set to `10`, mysqld did the rounding. It effectively ran `SELECT FORMAT(5/7,10);` thus, rounding `0.714285714285714285714285714285714285714285...` to 10 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Let's try 25

```
mysql> set div_precision_increment = 25;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'div_precision_increment';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| div_precision_increment | 25    |
+-------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1/7 + 2/7 + 2/7 sum2;
+-----------------------------+
| sum2                        |
+-----------------------------+
| 0.7142857142857142857142857 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since [**div_precision_increment**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) is set to `25`, mysqld did the rounding. It effectively ran `SELECT FORMAT(5/7,25);` thus, rounding `0.714285714285714285714285714285714285714285...` to 25 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: +1.Very useful answer. But my core question is why doesn't the `select 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3;` give `0.9999`? The `1/3` is `0.3333` according to the second select

Comment: Hi Ronaldo.May be I don't understand the answer. My confusion is: Why doesn't the `select 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3;` give 1.0? Because of the default rounding at 4 digits? Because I was expecting the result not to be 1.0 but 0.9999 because I consider `select 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3;` exactly the same as `select(0.3333 + 0.3333 + 0.3333);` since `select (1/3);` gives `0.333`. Can you please help me understand this?